# Docker ubunbu container , can't edit the source.list, no editor present

Tags: ubuntu, docker, container

Just installed a docker Ubuntu container.
All the repositories in the sources list are commented (#) and so I neither can update nor install anything via APT. 
There is no editor like nano ,vim etc. Now how do uncomment the entries in the source list ?

Comment: Do you have sed

Comment: It seems to me to be against the grain of a container to have updates applied to it. You'd more commonly deploy a newer container. Can you describe your reasons for updating the container internally?

Comment: can you provide the exact of the docker image ?

Comment: I installed the container through the `-it Ubuntu bash` command. As shown in the hello-world as an example.

Comment: @EchoMike444, I wanted to install some programs in it.

Comment: I think you'd be swimming upstream less if you built an image on top of the base that included the program's you want.

Answer (score 3):

if you run the official docker image **ubuntu**

```
docker run -it ubuntu  bash -i
```

an run this command **grep -v -e '^#' -e '^$' /etc/apt/sources.list** to show what you have in your file **/etc/apt/sources.list** .

see man of grep ( https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep )

you must see these lines :

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse
```

so after you must run **apt-get update**
and after you can run **apt-get install emacs-nox vim nano**

Comment: Just to make sure, will it remove all the '#' signs ? because there are also genuine comments in it.

Comment: this command **grep ..** display only that's matter .